# general_log.csv deleted by accident now error Can't get stat of './mysql/general_log.CSV' (Errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql, linux

We have a dedicated web server with a 50Gb partition for MySQL.

In order to do some tunning on MySQL, I turned on general_log var using:

```
set global general_log = 1; 
set global expire_logs_days = 30;
```

After 2 days the general_log.CSV took over all the free space in the partition, making MySQL unavailable.

Our tech support on the hosting company , solved that by deleting the file.
Now I need to turn on general_log again and I get this error:

```
Can't get stat of './mysql/general_log.CSV' (Errcode: 2)
```

What can I do to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: try `touch ./mysql/general_log.CSV` first ;)

Comment: edit: `su yourmysqluser` first, so mysql has rw permissions